# jasper pdf generation password prompt

Tags: passwords, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

This is for using Jasper JRPdfExporter to generate PDF. How can I set the custom message when prompt users to enter the password? The message will be "The password is using your last 4 digits of your id". I would like to know where I can set the message.

Comment: When user opens pdf?

Comment: Yes. Using configuration.setUserPassword("...."); When user tries to open the pdf, there will be prompt to enter the password. I would like to custom message for the prompt. Thank you

Comment: You can add java script to the pdf, configuration.setPdfJavaScript(), to prompt user, but I do not know if you can change the text in password dialog.

Comment: As far as i know you cannot change the password dialog text from within the pdf. After all, the password is needed to read the pdf in the first place...